# Should there be a constant tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just reading some question and felt that there should be constant tag in which all the constant should be included (plank's constant, Avogadro constant,etc).

Take a look at this [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11179/whats-the-acid-ionization-constant-of-the-hydrogen-proton) which according to me requires constant tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that would be a helpful tag, to be honest.  If you were able to find a series of questions on which it was actually appropriate (where the heart of each of the questions was actually focused on determining a constant, etc.), we could certainly look into it.

Just having a [constant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constant) tag would, in my experience, inspire people to add it just about any question involving formulas with constants, and at that point it would be adding to the noise rather than serving as a marker for experts to find questions.